# Issue with multiple tags for table of content

Tags: javascript

I have script which creates table of content based on `h2, h3` tags. In the code below it searches `h2` tags and create links based on that.

Problem is when any other tag `span` inside `h2` tag, it ignores that `h2` tag and does not create link for the same. I guess problem lies in the regex `/<h([\d]).*>\s*[\d]*\s?[.]?\s?([^<]+)<\/h([\d])>/gi` Since I am not good with regex, couldn't fix it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var toc = "";
  var level = 0;
  var maxLevel = 3;

  if (document.getElementById("contents") != null) {

    document.getElementById("contents").innerHTML =
      document.getElementById("contents").innerHTML.replace(
        /<h([\d]).*>\s*[\d]*\s?[.]?\s?([^<]+)<\/h([\d])>/gi,
        function(str, openLevel, titleText, closeLevel) {

          if (openLevel > maxLevel) {
            return str;
          }

          if (openLevel > level) {
            toc += (new Array(2)).join("<ol>");
          } else if (openLevel < level) {
            toc += (new Array(level - openLevel + 1)).join("</ol>");
          }

          level = parseInt(openLevel);

          var anchor = titleText.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]+/g, "-");

          toc += "<li><a href=\"#" + anchor + "\">" + titleText +
            "</a></li>";

          return "<a name=\"" + anchor + "\">" +
            "<h" + openLevel + "\">" + str + "</h" + closeLevel + ">" + "</a>";
        }
      );

    if (level) {
      toc += (new Array(level + 1)).join("</ol>");
    }

    document.getElementById("toc").innerHTML += toc;
  }

});
```

```css
.blink {
  animation: blinker 1s step-start infinite;
  color: #ff0000;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.85em;
}

@keyframes blinker {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="toc">
    <div id="contents">
      <h2>What is JS?</h2>
      <h2 style="margin-top:1em;">Python Jobs - <span class="blink">New!</span></h2>
      <h2 style="margin-top:1em;">
        What is Python?
      </h2><h3>Introduction</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried applying the `replace` regex to the `.innerText` property of the tag instead of the `.innerHTML` content? InnerHTML will include span tags, innerText only contains the text, ignoring tags.

Comment: Just tried, it breaks the code.

Comment: I had a closer look and notice you target the innerHTML of the content division (containing two h1 tags and linebreaks). If you're bulding links based on the text of the h1 tags, innerText will do it if targetted properly, regardless of any spans or other tags inside the html. Shall I post a suggestion or are you more concerned as to why your chosen method is not working and need to adapt that?

Comment: Any suggestion would be more than welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it without regex

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const toc = document.createElement('ol');

  if (document.getElementById("contents") != null) {
    document.getElementById("contents").append(toc);
    document.querySelectorAll("#contents h2").forEach((title) => {
      const item = document.createElement('li');
      const link = document.createElement('a');

      if (title.getAttribute('id') === null) {
        title.setAttribute('id', 'id-' + Math.random().toString(16).substr(2, 6));
      }

      link.innerText = title.innerText;
      link.setAttribute('href', '#' + title.getAttribute('id'));

      item.append(link);
      toc.append(item);
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.blink {
  animation: blinker 1s step-start infinite;
  color: #ff0000;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.85em;
}

@keyframes blinker {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="toc">
    <div id="contents">
      <h2>What is JS?</h2>
      <h2 style="margin-top:1em;">Python Jobs - <span class="blink">New!</span></h2>
      <h2 style="margin-top:1em;">
        What is Python?
      </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

---

Edit

You can still follow the hierarchy

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const toc = document.createElement('ol');
  let last = toc;

  if (document.getElementById("contents") != null) {
    document.getElementById("contents").append(toc);
    document.querySelectorAll("#contents h2, #contents h3").forEach((title) => {
      const item = document.createElement('li');
      const link = document.createElement('a');

      if (title.getAttribute('id') === null) {
        title.setAttribute('id', 'id-' + Math.random().toString(16).substr(2, 6));
      }

      link.innerText = title.innerText;
      link.setAttribute('href', '#' + title.getAttribute('id'));

      item.append(link);

      if (title.tagName === 'H2') {
        toc.append(item);
        last = item;
      } else {
        let ol = last.querySelector('ol');
        
        if (!ol) {
          ol = document.createElement('ol');
          last.append(ol);
        }

        ol.append(item);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.blink {
  animation: blinker 1s step-start infinite;
  color: #ff0000;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.85em;
}

@keyframes blinker {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="toc">
    <div id="contents">
      <h2>What is JS?</h2>
      <h3>A programing language</h3>
      <h2 style="margin-top:1em;">Python Jobs - <span class="blink">New!</span></h2>
      <h2 style="margin-top:1em;">
        What is Python?
      </h2>
      <h3>A cool programing language</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not return hierarchical indexing. For e.g. h3 link would be one level down to h2.

Comment: Done, it add h3 in the toc and still add random id, if not already present, for the anchor (still not the best id, totally random anchor will not work if a link is send to someone else nor a simple refresh, create an id based on title content should be a better idea)

Comment: Upvoting because this is a good answer based on the (lack) of information provided in the question. Also, regex on html is something to avoid and this answer provides an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

The snippet here creates an html collection of all the h2 tags inside the `.contents` div.

It then loops through the collection, extracting the `.innerText` of each (so ignoring the spans and other tags) before building a link from the `.replaced' text (to fill in non alphabet characters with dashes.

If you hover over the links created and examine the status bar, you will see they are valid links (you may need to refine your .replace to format them exactly as required but this gives a working principle to follow.

```js
let h2Collection = document.getElementById('contents').getElementsByTagName('h2');
// h2Collection is an array-like collection of h1 elements contained in the #contents div;
 
let links = [];

for (let i=0; i<h2Collection.length; i++) {

  links.push(`<a href="http://www.whateversite.com/${h2Collection[i].innerText.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]+/g, "-")}.html">${h2Collection[i].innerText}</a>`)

} // next i h2element;


document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = links.join('<p>');
```

```css
.blink {
  animation: blinker 1s step-start infinite;
  color: #ff0000;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 0.85em;
}

@keyframes blinker {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="toc">
    <div id="contents">
      <h2>What is <span style="color:red">JS?</span></h2>
      <h2 style="margin-top:1em;">Python Jobs - <span class="blink">New!</span></h2>
      <h2 style="margin-top:1em;">
        What is Python?
      </h2>
    </div>

    <div id=output></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this does not return hierarchical indexing. For e.g. h3 link would be one level down to h2. –

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question as it is asking about broken links caused by tags inside h2 elements. Perhaps also, include an example with h3 tags. (you would extract them exacly as both answers here suggest, targetting h3 as well as h2). Formatting is most likely trivial, if not, include why you can't do it in your question.

Comment: Edited my question with h3 tag